the bost isnt sending attachment
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Clear canvas with transparency
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Set text properties
    ctx.font = '40px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';

    // Draw welcome text
    ctx.fillText(`Welcome to the server, ${member.displayName}!`, 50, 100);

    // Load and draw member's avatar
    const avatar = await loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 50, 120, 80, 80); // Adjust position and size as needed

    // Create attachment from canvas buffer
    const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(await canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    // Send welcome message with attachment
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, { files: [attachment] });
});

I made discord.js bot using attachmentBuilder but the bot isn't sending image it just send welcome message without image:


Some of the commonly used methods have changed their syntax over the past few versions of discordjs.
Please refer to this guide:
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc
In your case, I believe you can now attach a file directly like this:
channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`, { files: ['./welcome-image.png'] })

